# C# Getting values to my controller from a multiple custom checkbox group

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my web site there is some check box which belong to 2 group.

I want to get check box which are selected.

This is my controller.

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult HireItem()
        {
            var HireItemListModel = new HireItemModel();

            HireItemListModel = new HireItemModel()
            {
                first_name = Session["first_name"].ToString(),
                middle_name = Session["middle_name"].ToString(),
                last_name = Session["last_name"].ToString(),
                ceremony_date = Session["ceremony_date"].ToString(),
            };       

            var product = _productService.GetAllHireProducts();

            if (product.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (var proValue in product)
                {
                    var productVarSeparateList = _productService.GetHireProductVariantsByProductIds(proValue.Id, false);

                    foreach (var HireProSep in productVarSeparateList)
                    {
                        var productVarSeparateModel = new HireItemModel.HireItemSeparatetModel()
                        {
                            pname = HireProSep.Name,
                            price =HireProSep.Price,
                            pId=HireProSep.Id,
                        };
                        HireItemListModel.HireItemSeparatetlist.Add(productVarSeparateModel);
                    }
                    var productVarSetList = _productService.GetHireProductVariantsByProductIds(proValue.Id, true);

                    foreach (var HireProset in productVarSetList)
                    {
                        var productVarListset = new HireItemModel.HireItemSetModel()
                        {
                            pname = HireProset.Name,
                            price = HireProset.Price,
                            pId = HireProset.Id,
                        };
                        HireItemListModel.HireItemSetList.Add(productVarListset);
                    }
                }
            }

            return View(HireItemListModel);

        }

        [HttpPost,ActionName("HireItem")]
        public ActionResult HireItem(string submitB)
        {

            var checkbox=Request.Form["HItemType"];
            if (checkbox != "false")
            {
                var HireItemArray = Request.Form["chk_group"];
//This is the problem...


                return RedirectToRoute("ShoppingCart");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToRoute("hire");

            }
}
```

This is my first Partial  view.

```
<table  >

 @foreach (var item in Model)
{
    var val = item.pId;
     <tr>
     <td>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_groupSet" value="@val" />
</td>
        <td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.pname)
   </td>
       <td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.price)
   </td>
        <td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.pId)
   </td>
   </tr>
}
</table>
```

This is my another Partial view

```
<table  >

 @foreach (var item in Model)
{
    var val = item.pId;


     <tr>
     <td> 
     <input type="checkbox" name="chk_group" value="@val" />


    @* @Html.CheckBox("separateHireItem",""+item.pId )*@
     @*<input type="checkbox" name="sItem" value="sItem"  />*@</td>
        <td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.pname)
   </td>
        <td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.price)
   </td>
        <td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.pId)
   </td>
   </tr>
}

</table>
```

My question is I get flowing output.

[image: I don't understand what this mean]

I want to get the values of  check boxes which are selected..

Comment: This looks like to me that the Post is returning an Array of HItemType also I would suggest you to use FormCollection in your HireItem action as paramter

Comment: It would be useful to also see the structure of `HireItemListModel` too. Out of interest, why doesn't `_productService.GetAllHireProducts()` fully hydrate the hire item list to send to the view, as opposed to performing a load of additional data loading in the controller action?